# Angular multiple directives in different templates that share a scope

Tags: angularjs

I built a pagination system in Angular, but it has one design flaw that I can't figure out.

I need to be able to call this directive from different template files and share the same pages scope. I've tried isolated scopes, but it needs to be able to change the scope of the items that needs to be paginated that's being defined in the controller.

Here's a working example: http://plnkr.co/edit/Qw2NmakYRlse1Eo7MESh?p=preview

You can see the problem when you click on one of the pagers, and the other doesn't update with it.

The pagination directive changes the scope.pages array. Then the template, using that array, changes the pager.

```
app.directive('pagination', function(){
  return {
    restrict: "A",
    templateUrl:'pagination.html',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The templates are not updated because there are not sharing the same scope, try with this updated version:

http://plnkr.co/edit/E1DLOacahykSwWBWhHhU?p=preview

The trick might be to enable two way binding:

```
return {
  restrict: "A",
  scope: {
    items: '='
  },
```

and use this object to store your pages.

```
scope.items = [/*list of pages*/]
```

Comment: I'm having some troubles getting this to work. Everything is the same as the plunker but items is dynamic so it has to make an $http request first. items is undefined in the directive.

Comment: added a $watch on items and then called an init functions. Thanks for your help :)